# Filter SharePoint List based on value from another list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, development, filter

Scenario:
I have two lists. One tracking all the points an individual has amassed, another showing all the prizes that this person can win.

I would like to display on one page, the total number of points (sum of points) and a filtered list, of all the prizes that the person qualifies for, based on their total number of points amassed.

How would I go about filtering the 'Prizes' list based on the value of the sum of points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [List Filter View Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Filter-Web-Part-to-a-List-View-Web-Part-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).  Scroll down on the page to the section, 'Connect a List Filter Web Part to a List View Web Part for SharePoint 2016 and 2013'. The text (without images) is posted below:

To edit a page you must be a member of the Members SharePoint group for the site.

From a page, in the ribbon click the Page tab, and then click the Edit command.

Page tab with Edit button highlighted

NOTE:  If the Edit command is disabled, you may not have the permissions to edit the page. Contact your administrator..

Click the page where you want to insert a SharePoint List Filter Web Part and a List View Web Part.

In the ribbon, click the Insert tab, and then click Web Part.

Insert ribbon on Wiki page

Under Categories, click Lists and Libraries, under Web Parts, click the List View Web Part you want, and then click Add. The new Web Part appears on the page.

Click the Web Part menu down arrow for the List View Web Part, and then point to Modify Shared Web Part.

In the Web Part tool pane, edit the custom Web Part properties by doing the following:

To change the default view of the list, select a different view from the Selected View list box. For example, you may want to filter, sort, or group data a different way or display different columns. Alternatively, click Edit the current view to edit the current view of the list.

List views property pane
Whenever you select or edit a list view, a copy of the list design is made from the original site list design and saved with the List View Web Part. However, the list data remains the same.

Be careful when you switch to a different view from the current view. You may delete changes that you made to the current view and may disable Web Part connections that depend on columns in the current view. You are prompted for confirmation if you switch views.

To change the toolbar, under ToolBar Type, select Full Toolbar, Summary Toolbar, or No Toolbar from the list box.

Select a toolbar type
At the bottom of the tool pane, click OK.

Under Categories click Filters, under Web Parts click SharePoint List Filter, and then click Add. The new Web Part appears on the page.

To configure the Web Part, do one of the following:

In the Web Part, click Open the tool pane.

Point to the Web Part, click the down arrow, and then click Edit Web Part. The configuration tool pane appears.

In the tool pane, type a name in the Filter Name box to identify the Web Part.

You can also use the name as a label or a brief instruction to the user. For example, you can use Filter Reports By: as a label to tell users they can filter the view of a Reports list.

To specify a SharePoint list, enter the URL of a list in the List box, or click Browse next to the text box and search for the list you want.

Optionally, to select a different list view, select an item from the View list box. For example, you may want to filter, sort, or group data a different way or display different columns.

Select a column from the Value field list box. The value column displays all supported columns from the list. Some columns are not supported, such as Title, Calculated, and Multiple lines of text.

IMPORTANT:  When you make the connection between the SharePoint List Filter Web Part and the List View Web Part, make sure you choose a column that has matching values to the Value field property.

NOTE:  A SharePoint List Filter Web Part has a limit of 100 items.

Optionally, select a column from the Description field list box. The description column is used to display an alternative value in the Select Filter Value(s) dialog box, which displays when a user clicks the Filter button. For example, if you have a Month number column that uses the numbers 1 though 12 as month values, you can use a Month Name column as the Description column so that January is displayed instead of 1, February instead of 2, and so on.

Optionally, in the Advanced Filter Options section, do one or more of the following:

In the Control width in pixels text box, enter a number indicating the width of the text box as the number of pixels, or an empty value or "0" to automatically size the text box. Because the value entered by the user appears in this text box, you probably want to make it wide enough for the largest possible value.

To display a message that reminds the user to make a choice to filter the data, select the Require user to choose a value check box.

To enter an initial value in the SharePoint List Filter Web Part text box, enter a default value in the Default Value box, a value that typically matches one of the values in the column specified in step 13 or step 14. This default value is then used to display the initial list of values in the List View Web Part when the page first appears.

To enable users to filter by a null value, select "(Empty)" value. For example, users may want to see all values in a column that have no entry. To enable the clearing of a filter so that users can see all the values in the List View Web Part, select Allow Multiple selections.

NOTE:  The Select Filter Value(s) dialog box displays check boxes, rather than radio buttons.

A user cannot use this feature to display the filtered results of two or more selections, because The List View Web Part does not support multiple selections. If a user chooses multiple selections, only the first selection is used.

To save your changes, at the bottom of the tool pane, click OK.

To connect the SharePoint List Filter Web Part, point to the SharePoint List Filter Web Part, click the down arrow, point to Connections, point to Send Filter Values To, and then click the name of the List View Web Part to which you want to connect.

NOTE: If you don't see Connections on the menu, click Edit Web Part to open properties, and then click the down arrow again. You can open properties on either the filter or the list web parts.

In the Configure Connection dialog box, select the column that you want to filter in the List View Web Part, and then click Finish.

When you are done configuring the connection, in Page tab, click Save & Close to save and view the page

To dynamically change the results in the List View Web Part, in the SharePoint List Filter Web Part, click Filter, click a value, and then click OK. If you selected the Allow Multiple selections property, to redisplay all the values in the List View Web Part, you must clear all the check boxes, and then click OK.