# Compare values between lists

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there an easier (no code, no plugin) way to test if a date from one list falls among the date on another list? (so essentially checking if a date = holiday)

I tried lookup column but this is insufficient. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use data view web part to filter data in one list based on the data in another list SharePoint

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210504/filter-sharepoint-list-based-on-value-from-another-list

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can set second list data view web part to get parameter from first list, then filter the second list based on the parameters get from first list, try the following steps:

1. Insert two web part zone, then insert data views for first list and second list.
2. For the second list data view web part, in Common Data View Tasks, choose Web Part Connections.
3. Set the Web Part Connections as below:

   - choose the action on the source web part to use for this connection: Get Parameter From
   - choose Connect to a Web Part on this page
   - set choose the columns in the source web part which match the input parameters for the target web part: column in first list: field1   input to second list: paramenter1, column in first list: field2 input to second list: parameter2
4. In Common Data View Tasks, set filter for second list, filter the field in second list based on the conditions and parameters.

**FYI: [Connect data in Web Parts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA101785157.aspx)**

Comment: Hi, I am trying to see if a date is a holiday (returning a yes/no) Thank you for your efforts but your answer only filters/provides view; not a decision